# __contains__ and Python3.8 enum.Enum

Tags: python, enums

**SETUP**: Python 3.8.2; Some Enum Class with an overloaded `__contains__()` function.

```
  from enum import Enum
  
  class Something(Enum):
      A = 1
      def __contains__(self, Other):
          return Other in self.__class__.__members__.keys()
```

**TEST 1**: Using values from the enum itself.

```
  print("A:", Something.A in Something)
```

works fine (here result = `A: True`).

**TEST 2**: Using non-enum values.

```
  print("1:", 1 in Something)
```

fails with an exception, namely

```
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 'in': 'int' and 'EnumMeta'
```

**QUESTION**:

How is it possible to achieve an `in` functionality (membership operator) where the left operand can be anything? That is, it should be possible to write something like

```
if anything in Something:
    ...
```

without having to check the type of `anything`.

Comment: `Something.__contains__` is for checking if a value is in an *instance* of `Something`. To check if something is in the class itself, you need to override `__contains__` at the metaclass level.

Comment: Ok. Would you, please, explain how this can be done and make this into an answer?

Comment: Trying to figure that out...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Defining `Something.__contains__` lets you write something like `1 in Something.A`. For what you want, you would need to subclass `EnumMeta` and use the result in defining `Something`.

In some sense, `Enum.__new__` *already* does the check we want; passing a value to the type either returns the appropriate instance, or raises a `ValueError`.

```
>>> Something.A
<Something.A: 1>
>>> Something(Something.A)
<Something.A: 1>
>>> Something(1)
<Something.A: 1>
>>> Something(3)
ValueError: 3 is not a valid Something

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
```

So, our new metaclass's `__contains__` method simply has to try to retrieve the given value from the given type, returning `True` if it succeeds and `False` if an exception is raised.

```
from enum import EnumMeta, Enum

class MyMeta(EnumMeta):

    def __contains__(self, other):
        try:
            self(other)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        else:
            return True


class Something(Enum, metaclass=MyMeta):
    A = 1


assert Something.A in Something
assert 1 in Something
assert 2 not in Something
```

If you want `1 in Something` to return `False` instead, just catch the `TypeError` raised by `super().__contains__`.

```
class MyMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __contains__(self, other):
        try:
            return super().__contains__(other)
        except TypeError:
            return False
```

Comment: What if I want ``1 in Something`` to be ``False``? Personally, I prefer ``__contains()`` to be ``return Other in cls.__members__.values()``.